# How to make a shortcut for program with php

Tags: php, xampp

How to make a shortcut for program in Windows to a target folder with php

for example i want to create or copy  shortcut for xampp-control.exe to StartUp folder in Windows

to this path C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp

Answer (score 1):

Try [`symlink(<target_location>, <link_location>)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.symlink.php).

You will need write access to the `link_location` folder though. To check if you can write to the "StartUp" folder use [`is_writeable(<link_location>)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable).

Example:

```
symlink('c:\runMe.exe', 'c:\users\<username>\desktop\linkToRunMeExe');
```